# Declare functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I have this code:

```
function myFunction(){
    alert("Hello");
}
```

And this other code:

```
var myFunction = function(){

}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is the normal way to declare a function in javascript. You call it by referring to its name, myfunction().

The second is an anonymous function that is stored in a variable as functions are first class citizens in javascript. The variable myfunction now holds the anonymous function.

Basically the first is a normal function while the second is a variable holding an anonymous function.

Comment: And the second one is harder to debug since its name wont be showed in stack traces

Answer (score 0):

The first is a named function, which if you were to look at a stack trace, you'd see `myFunction` when it was called.

The second is a variable set to an anonymous function.  In a stack trace, this function would have an `<anonymous>` as it's name, making it harder to trace when there are many anonymous functions.

Comment: While your statement is true, it gives the impression that using anonymous function is bad. It is not, and there are many arguments for it. Worst case, it is debatable.

Comment: I never said it was bad, just hard to debug haha, there are plenty of times when to use both, and both even together. In fact anonymous functions are great for providing scope, I'm trying to get at self-instantiation with that.

Comment: No problem, as I said, it gave the impression. I just wanted to make it clear for a beginner that might read your comment and think that they should never use anonymous functions.